# Good introductory papers and books on laser physics and pulsed lasers

Tags: resource-recommendations, laser

I am looking for good introductory papers and/or books on the principles of lasers. In particular, I am interested in pulsed laser technology.

I understand that

> Gould, R. Gordon (1959). "The LASER, Light Amplification by Stimulated Emission of Radiation"

was one of the principal papers published by the disputed inventor himself. What are other good sources?

Comment: First optical laser made by Maiman in 1960. See http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v187/n4736/abs/187493a0.html

Comment: CW lasers? Pulsed lasers? just lasers (i.e. population inversion and stuff like that?)?

Comment: if you want u can cite Einstein on the matter of Stimulated emission.. such as Maria Goppert Mayer is always cited on matter of two-photon excitation.. it's always cool to cite einstein! :)

Comment: @gigacyan - Interesting. @Steve - You make a valid point, actually I am mostly interested in pulsed laser technology. @Steve - I agree, Einstein is a heavy guy to quote.

Comment: First learn the fundamentals in wikipidea, and you will find plenty of references there..

Comment: We used "Laser Fundamentals", William T. Silfvast when I took a course on lasers. I didn't like it much to be honest, it contains a lot more information than I found interesting.  There is an Oxford Master's lasers book by Simon Hooker that might be good, I like that series.

Answer (score 3):

This answer contains some additional resources that may be useful. **Please note that answers which simply list resources but provide no details are strongly discouraged by [the site's policy on resource recommendation questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed)**. This answer is left here to contain additional links that do not yet have commentary.

- Rüdiger Paschotta: *Encyclopedia of Laser Physics and Technology*, [online version](http://www.rp-photonics.com/topics.html) or [paper version](http://www.wiley-vch.de/publish/en/books/bySubjectEE00/ISBN3-527-40828-2).
- You can look for *LIA Handbook of Laser Material Processing*  or *Laser Processing of Engineering Materials* by John C. Ion.
- Orazio Svelto, *Principles of Lasers*, 4th edition. Springer, 1998. This is a good all-round book about lasers.
- [*Femtosecond Laser Pulses: Principles and Experiments*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Femtosecond-Laser-Pulses-Principles-Experiments/dp/0387017690)  by Claude Rulliere (ed.) helped me a lot during the writing on my master thesis on femtosecond pulsed lasers.